# The operation has timed out error while accessing the hosted webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

Hi I have created a very simple service, which will return true. The code snippet is as follows.

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Service1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public bool CompileProject()
    {

        return true;

    }
}
```

when i try to access the above method after hosting the service in IIS, i only get the operation timed out exception.

I have set the timeout property to 500000 milliseconds. Eventhough i get this exception.

Any suggestion or am i missing anything.

-Lokesh.

Comment: do you get the wsdl displayed when you browse to the web service using a web browser?